# How can i repeat the macro for the whole range of cells and columns?

Tags: excel, vba

Basically i'm linking the cells of workbook1 with workbook2, what is the code to do that for the whole spreadsheet?
my fault not clearly explained, as you can see below i'm assigning the value of the cells in workbook1 from workbook2

```
Sub Macro2() 
    Windows("workbook2.xlsx").Activate 
    Windows("workbook1.xlsx").Activate 
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _ 
       "='[workbook2.xlsx]workbook1'!R18C1" 
    Range("A19").Select 
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "='[workbook2.xlsx]workbook1'!R19C1" 
    Range("A20").Select 
    ......... 
End Sub
```

i was wondering whats the fastest way to do that for the range A9 to A120, E9 to E120, F9 to F120.....

Comment: What do you mean by linking the whole spreadsheet? each cell or...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub CopyPasteEntries()
 Dim i, g, h As Integer
 Sheets("Sheet1").Select
 Range("A1").EntireRow.Copy
 Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
 i = 2
 Sheets("Sheet1").Select
  Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1))  
  i = i + 1        
  Loop
  g = i - 1
  h = 2
  For i = 2 To g 
 Sheets("Sheet1").Select
  If Cells(i, 1).Value <> "Created" Then
   Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Copy
 Sheets("Sheet2").Select
   Cells(h, 1).Select
 ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
 h = h + 1
 End If     
  Next
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
 End Sub
```

Comment: amazing thnx, exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

This code will link all cells in all worksheets:

```
Sub LinkSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        ws.UsedRange.FormulaR1C1 = "='[workbook2.xlsx]" & ws.Name & "'!RC"
    Next

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

If you only want to link certain cells from one workhsheet, try this code:

```
Sub LinkRange()
    Workbooks("workbook1.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1"). _
        Range("A9:A120,E9:E120,F9:F120").FormulaR1C1= _
        "='[workbook2.xlsx]Sheet1'!RC"
End Sub
```

Comment: Sub Macro()

    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=[book2.xlsx]Sheet1!R2C1"

    Range("A3").Select

    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=[book2.xlsx]Sheet1!R3C1"

    Range("A4").Select

    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=[book2.xlsx]Sheet1!R4C1"

    Range("A5").Select

End Sub

Comment: Where do you get the subscript out of range error - in the second macro? if so, check that the names of the workbooks and worksheets are correct!